# XPATH syntax validator in Python

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, web-crawler

I develop a crawler with many actions. Many xpaths are involving and for this reason I use a json file for storing. Then crawler start running I would like to make a basic syntax check (before xpath usage) on xpaths and raise error for invalid xpaths.

for example:

```
xpath1 = '//*[@id="react-root"]/section'
xpath2 = '//*[[@id="react-root"]/section'
xpath3 = '//*[@id="react-root"]\section'
```

from these xpaths only xpath1 is valid

is there any module or regex which does this kind of validation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can compile the xpath strings with [`lxml.etree.XPath`](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-class) which will raise an exception if the syntax is incorrect:

```python
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> lxml.etree.XPath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section')
//*[@id="react-root"]/section
>>> lxml.etree.XPath('//*[[@id="react-root"]/section')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
lxml.etree.XPathSyntaxError: Invalid expression
>>> lxml.etree.XPath(r'//*[@id="react-root"]\section')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
lxml.etree.XPathSyntaxError: Invalid expression
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
from selenium import webdriver;
webdriver.Chrome().find_elements('xpath', '//*[text(),"invalid xpath"]')
```