# XPath Evaluation in Python Strings

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code, xpath, pycharm

I am writing a selenium project where a lot of code looks like this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@name="login"]').send_keys("testuser")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@name="password"]').send_keys("password123")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@type="submit"]').click()
result = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '////div[@class="card__item" and .//div[contains(text(), "Resultinfo")]]//h6[@id="title"]').text
```

Inside my Editor (Pycharm) the XPATH-String is not evaluated by the IDE.

When I'm having some kind of syntax error (happens alot) I won't get informed. Which is annoying since the programm is sometimes running for a few minutes before reaching the flawed line.
It doesn't have to evaluated against a document. Just if the Syntax is right.

Does someone know a fitting plugin or hack how to handle this in a better way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know there is no such plugin for Pycharm and since xpath evaluation for regular strings would create a lot of noise, I doubt such plugin will be available soon. But you can compile xpath expressions in the python console prior running (to catch typos). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50152379/8375783

Comment: using the method Trapli has linked you can create a preLaunchTask python script to test the XPATH strings in the `find_element` calls, maybe VSC will cancel the launch based on the `sys.exit()` value of the task